# jpa recursive persistence depth - saving nested objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to understand the right way to handle persisting objects with JPA.  I created four related objects, each owns a `Set<?>` of the children.  I added bidirectional mappings.  I created a test where I added one of each up the chain and then tried to persist the set.  It appears I can't go beyond an immediate relationship.  Is that the case?  Is it expected I have to build a service for each object that performs the adding of a child to a parent rather than directly using the accessors?

Ok, let's say I have these objects:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = B.class
            , mappedBy = "a"
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = C.class
            , mappedBy = "b"
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<C> cs;
}

@Entity
public class C implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private B b;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = D.class
            , mappedBy = "c"
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<D> ds;
}

@Entity
public class D implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false
            , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private C c;
}
```

And, then I create one of each and add it to the previous relative:

```
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.getBs().add(b);
    C c = new C();
    b.getCs().add(c);
    D d = new D();
    c.getDs().add(d);
```

If I then persist it (`dService.save(d);`) it fails because C's id doesn't exist.  Since the value has to be generated by saving it, I would have expected it to recursively travel up the change and save A first, and then fill in from there.  If I start with A (`aService.save(a);`) I get the same error on B.  It behaves like there's no cascade.

Comment: Can you be more concrete in your example? Is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I believe [this blog](https://notesonjava.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/managing-the-bidirectional-relationship/) answers my questions.  Or at least goes a long way.  And, ironically, ended up creating nearly identical objects.